# Windows Server 2012 - How to set up Domain Controller Trust?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, internal-dns

I'm attempting to set up a test system to replicate the following environment:

Two AD domain controllers serving two separate domains, mycorp.local and mycorp.hq. It's not exposed to the outside world and are on the same network.

I'm trying to set them up so that they trust each other, so that a Windows 8.1 machine that is configured for mycorp.local can have someone from mycorp.hq can log into it.

But when I try to add a trust I get the following message.

[image: Cannot Continue]

I'm assuming that it is down to DNS, both Windows Server 2012 machines have a DNS server running on it but how do I add the other domain to my DNS servers so they can resolve the domain name?

Or is there another issue?

Comment: Have you tried doing an nslookup to confirm that it's a DNS issue?

Comment: Just tried `*** UnKnown can't find mycorp.local: Non-existent domain` from mycorp.nq DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up Conditional Forwarders on each DC/DNS server for the other AD domain.

So the mycorp.local DC/DNS server forwards DNS queries for the mycorp.hq domain to the mycorp.hq DC/DNS server and vice versa.

When setting this up, you can ignore the following error if you are sure that the server allows Zone Transfers for your DNS Server.

[image]

Comment: That was my suspicion, but is wasn't sure how. Just tried and got the error `the server with this IP address is not authoritative for the required zone` and when trying to [set up authoritative zone](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739089%28WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) I get the same error. Any ideas?